# how to add flask-login to flask-admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

Login works great on my standard views, and the admin works great, but i can't seem to add login to my admin/yikes!!!

It seems straightforward [flask admin docs](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/v1.0.7/quickstart/#authentication) but when I add this section

```
class MyView(BaseView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        return login.current_user.is_authenticated()

    def _handle_view(self, name, **kwargs):
        if not self.is_accessible():
            return redirect(url_for('login', next=request.url))
```

I don't get sent to the login page for unauthenticated users.

any idea what else i need to do?

Does this look correct in my **init** file?

```
from flask.ext.admin import BaseView


class MyView(BaseView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        return login.current_user.is_authenticated()

    def _handle_view(self, name, **kwargs):
        if not self.is_accessible():
            return redirect(url_for('login', next=request.url))

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
Bootstrap(app)
from app import views, models
admin = Admin(app)


admin.add_view(ModelView(models.User, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(models.rutable, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(models.rustage, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(models.TOC, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(models.Request, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(models.Staff, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(models.Status, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(models.Challenge, db.session))
```

here are my login views which are connected to ldap auth

```
from flask.ext.admin import BaseView


def logged_in(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if session.get('logged_in') is not None:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('Please log in first...', 'error')
            next_url = request.url
            login_url = '%s?next=%s' % (url_for('login'), next_url)
            return redirect(login_url)
    return decorated_function


@login_manager.unauthorized_handler
def unauthorized():
    print 'unauthorized'
    flash("You must be logged in.")
    return redirect(url_for("login"))

@login_manager.user_loader
def user_loader(user_id):
    """Given *user_id*, return the associated User object.
    :param unicode user_id: user_id (email) user to retrieve
    """
    g.user=current_user
    return models.User.query.get(user_id)

@app.route("/logout")
# @logged_in
def logout():
    logout_user()
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash("Logged Out.")
    return redirect(url_for("login"))

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = current_user

@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if app.config['ENVIRONMENT']=='dev':
            try:
                print "Authentification Successful" 
                namedb=models.User.query.filter_by(name=unicode(form.username.data)).first()
                email=models.User.query.first().email         
                login_user(user_loader(unicode(email)),remember=form.remember_me.data)
                flash("Logged in successfully.")
                g.email=email
                session['logged_in'] = True
                return redirect( request.values.get('next') or url_for("main"))
            except Exception as e:
                flash("Invalid Credentials.")
                return render_template("login.html", form=form)
        else:
            try:
                if '@' in form.username.data:
                    form.username.data=re.sub(' /d+','', (re.sub("\d+",'', form.username.data.split('@')[0]))[1:]+(re.sub("\d+",'', form.username.data.split('@')[0]))[0:1])
                l = ldap.initialize("ldap://10.129.18.101")
                l.simple_bind_s("program\%s" % form.username.data,form.password.data)
                print "Authentification Successful"
                r=l.search_s('cn=Users,dc=BHCS,dc=Internal',ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,'(sAMAccountName=*%s*)' % form.username.data,['mail','objectGUID','displayName'])
                email=r[0][1]['mail'][0]   
                GUID=r[0][1]['objectGUID'][0]   
                FullName=r[0][1]['displayName'][0] 
                import uuid
                guid = uuid.UUID(bytes=GUID)
                if not models.User.query.filter_by(email=unicode(email)).first(): 
                  p=models.User(name=FullName,email=email)
                  db.session.add(p)
                  db.session.commit()            
                login_user(user_loader(unicode(email)),remember=form.remember_me.data)
                flash("Logged in successfully.")
                g.email=email
                session['logged_in'] = True
                return redirect( request.values.get('next') or url_for("main"))
            except Exception as e:
                flash("Invalid Credentials.")
                return render_template("login.html", form=form)
    return render_template("login.html", form=form)
```

As requested, here is my user class from my model

```
class User(db.Model):
    """An admin user capable of viewing reports.

    :param str email: email address of user
    :param str password: encrypted password for the user

    """
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    name=db.Column(db.String)
    email = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    authenticated = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)
    admin =  db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    def is_active(self):
        """True, as all users are active."""
        return True

    def get_id(self):
        """Return the email address to satisfy Flask-Login's requirements."""
        return self.email

    def is_authenticated(self):
        """Return True if the user is authenticated."""
        return self.authenticated

    def is_anonymous(self):
        """False, as anonymous users aren't supported."""
        return False
```

Comment: Do you get sent anywhere at all, are there errors, etc? also regarding this line: `if app.config['ENVIRONMENT']=='dev':` what is app.config in the environment where you are testing this?

Comment: I get sent straight to the admin console when i go to mysite/admin/.  There is no difference between my development environment and production, and it behaves the same in both.  thank you for helping!

Comment: How does your User class look like?

Comment: I'll post it in the original question at the bottom.  thanks!

Comment: So your authenticated is always True?

Comment: for testing purposes I don't restrict access in the dev environment, but i don't have any problem with the login in production, it works very well at restricting access e.g. when the password is incorrect. thanks again

Comment: anything glaringly obvious @Sean Vieira ?

Comment: Have you checked [that example](https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/blob/fe6f14e6b7606931d20925a96b4de7cff11447b9/examples/auth/app.py)?

Comment: Wow, finally got it working by starting fresh and using the example.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error (more error) I finally copied enough from the example (partial understanding) to get it working.  It seems I needed to add a super to MyAdminIndexView() to get it working.

That is I moved my "MyView" function out of the init and added this line

```
admin = Admin(app, 'example',index_view=views.MyAdminIndexView())
```

Changed my view significantly based on the example

```
class MyModelView(sqla.ModelView):

    def is_accessible(self):
        return g.user.is_authenticated()

class MyAdminIndexView(admin.AdminIndexView):
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        if not g.user.is_authenticated():
            flash('Please log in first...', 'error')
            next_url = request.url
            login_url = '%s?next=%s' % (url_for('login'), next_url)
            return redirect(login_url)
        # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        if g.user.admin == True:
            return super(MyAdminIndexView,self).index()
        else:
            return redirect(url_for("main"))

def logged_in(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if session.get('logged_in') is not None:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('Please log in first...', 'error')
            next_url = request.url
            login_url = '%s?next=%s' % (url_for('login'), next_url)
            return redirect(login_url)
    return decorated_function


@login_manager.unauthorized_handler
def unauthorized():
    print 'unauthorized'
    flash("You must be logged in.")
    return redirect(url_for("login"))

@login_manager.user_loader
def user_loader(user_id):
    """Given *user_id*, return the associated User object.
    :param unicode user_id: user_id (email) user to retrieve
    """
    g.user=current_user
    return models.User.query.get(user_id)

@app.route("/logout")
# @logged_in
def logout():
    logout_user()
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash("Logged Out.")
    return redirect(url_for("login"))

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = current_user
```

Comment: Why is the authentication status stored in the database? Wouldn't it be a dynamic value based on whatever you chose for authentication?